# Now to remove certain rows from 2d Numpy array when they match a given critera?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a very large 2d Numpy array (a few columns but billions of rows). As the program runs, I get more of those, thousands of them are generated.

For each one, I'd like to remove all rows that contains certain values in certain positions. For example, if I had:

```
arr = np.array([
    [10, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 1, 2],
    [3, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 1, 2]
    [3, 4, 2, 7],
    [3, 2, 1, 9],
    [3, 2, 2, 2],
]),
```

I'd like to remove all rows that contain the value 2 on positions 1 and 3, so that I would end up with:

```
print(arr)
>>> ([
    [10, 1, 1, 1],
    [3, 1, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 2, 7],
    [3, 2, 1, 9],
]),
```

Because I have such large 2d arrays and so many of them, I'm trying to do this with a Numpy call so that it runs in C, instead of iterating and selecting rows in Python which is much, much slower.

Is there a Numpy way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Eduardo

Comment: But with that said, the numpy way of doing this is: `arr[(arr[:,[1,3]] != 2).any(1)]`

Comment: @Psidom haha thanks, fantastic! I got 256GB on this workstation, but dont use nearly as much because the arrays are uint8 actually.

If you post it as an answer I can accept it - thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*boolean array indexing*](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing): i.e. select the 2nd and 4th column and then check that not all of them are equal to 2:

```
arr[(arr[:, [1,3]] != 2).any(1)]
array([[10,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 3,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 3,  4,  2,  7],
       [ 3,  2,  1,  9]])
```